# Why so Long time span in creating Session Factory?

Tags: linux, hibernate, spring

My project is web application running in the tomcat container. This application is a spring framework based hibernate application.

The problem with this is it takes a lot of time when creates session factory. here is the logs

```
2010-04-15 23:05:28,053 DEBUG [SessionFactoryImpl] Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
2010-04-15 23:05:28,053 DEBUG [SessionFactoryImpl] instantiating session factory with properties: {java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, catalina.base=/usr/local/InstalledPrograms/apache-tomcat-6.0.20, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Tiered Compilers, catalina.useNaming=true, os.name=Linux, sun.boot.class.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/classes, java.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/InstalledPrograms/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/conf/logging.properties, java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., hibernate.generate_statistics=true, java.runtime.version=1.6.0_17-b04, hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider, user.name=root, shared.loader=, tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled=true, hibernate.connection.release_mode=auto, user.language=en, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/i386, java.version=1.6.0_17, java.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager, user.timezone=Canada/Pacific, sun.arch.data.model=32, java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/InstalledPrograms/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/endorsed, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper.,sun.beans., file.separator=/, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=50.0, user.country=US, java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre, java.vm.info=mixed mode, os.version=2.6.18-128.el5, path.separator=:, java.vm.version=14.3-b01, hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=25, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, package.definition=sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper., java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming, sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000, user.home=/root, java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., java.library.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/i386:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib, java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/, java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000, common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, java.class.path=:/usr/local/InstalledPrograms/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/bootstrap.jar, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.vm.specification.version=1.0, catalina.home=/usr/local/InstalledPrograms/apache-tomcat-6.0.20, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true, hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider, java.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/InstalledPrograms/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/temp, java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi, server.loader=, os.arch=i386, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, java.ext.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext, user.dir=/, line.separator=, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.6, hibernate.show_sql=true}
2010-04-15 23:08:53,516 DEBUG [AbstractEntityPersister] Static SQL for entity: com.vsd.model.Order
```

There you can see the time delay of more than 3 mins in executing these processes. My database is mysql and database server is running on the local machine only. The container environment is Centos Linux system.

I am clueless about why it takes that much of time in executing these process, But when i do the same task from under eclipse it does not take that much of time. Development environment is Windows.

Comment: Take a thread dump during the creation of sessionFactory and post it to http://pastie.org

Comment: How to take Thread Dump. I start the tomcat as a service.

Comment: The Tomcat Monitor supports generating thread dumps (right click on the icon in the systray (see http://techwheel.blogspot.com/2010/03/thread-dump-in-tomcat.html).

Comment: I have created the thread dump and posted it here. Please see it http://pastie.org/924286

Comment: Arf, sorry, I should have written: take some thread dumps (e.g. ~5, one every 30s) during the creation of the SessionFactory (the idea is to analyze things over time).

Answer (score 2):

Are you connecting remotely to the database instance on Centos from your development environment or do you have a separate database instance? If you have a separate instance, are you certain that they contain the same tables and indexes?

Can you find out what SQL is being executed for com.vsd.model.Order? Try running the same SQL query by hand on each database instance to see if the behaviour is the same. This will tell you whether to concentrate on the database or on the Spring/Hibernate application code.

Comment: There are separate database for both environments.

Yes richj, I am sure. As database is created by me and tables are created by hibernate.

Once the connection is made. I can see sql being executed. The time taken here is completely in making connection. once connection is made it works well.

Comment: Is it also slow to create a connection using the mysql command line? If not, I wonder if the container's connection pool has handed out all of its connections and has to wait until one is returned (or some time-out interval has passed) before it can answer your request?

Comment: OK - then I would look at the container's connection pool. The application might be leaking connections by not returning them to the pool (e.g. with connection.close()) correctly. Code that obtains a connection without returning it from inside a corresponding finally block is one likely cause of this problem.

Comment: I am out of my mind. please suggest me how can i get the thread dump of tomcat process. which is running as service.

Comment: I can suggest, but I've no idea what it will do to a production server. Send the Tomcat process the quit signal, e.g. "kill -3 <process-id>" on Linux. This is similar to pressing Ctrl+Break in a Windows console running a JRE.

Comment: @richj Generating thread dumps on production servers is very common and doesn't harm the servers.